# Hibernate Session and Criteria

Tags: hibernate

org.hibernate.Criteria is an interface.

How is following possible then?

```
Criteria crit = sess.createCriteria(Cat.class);  
crit.setMaxResults(50);
List cats = crit.list();
```

How can anyone invoke methods on criteria interface without implementing the interface in first place?

e.g.

```
crit.setMaxResults
crit.list();
```

something fundamental I dont get here. help me out

Answer (score 0):

Session interface does have implementations one of them is `org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl`. Have a look at source code for #createCriteria method.

Comment: returns "sub criteria". Still confused

Comment: `org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.Subcriteria` is also implementation of `org.hibernate.Criteria`.

Answer (score 0):

You declare a variable using the interface - desgin to interfaces, but it can be of any type that implements that interface.

`sess.createCriteria` returns I would guess, [Criteriaimpl](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/impl/CriteriaImpl.html). (way to go on naming there hibernate).

Have a look at the collections framework aswell for excellent use interfaces.

Comment: thanks for answering. Noted ur point abt design to interfaces.However, API says it returns Criteria or "sub criteria" though.

Comment: yeah that does to contradict anythign I said, just like an arraylist is a List. a CriterieaImpl is a Criteria, only the methods exposed by itnerface are accessible.